# Google Domains Not Pointing to Correct Heroku App

Tags: heroku

I am trying to point my Google Domains domain name to Heroku, but am having a hard time.  I previously had the domain forwarded to point to another website, but I have now followed [these instructions](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6346300?hl=en) to point it to my Heroku app.

The domain in question is [www.lizbayardelle.com](http://www.lizbayardelle.com).  The Heroku app I want it to is https://liz-bayardelle.herokuapp.com/.  If I type `heroku open` in Terminal this is what comes up.  However, if you go to the domain and the heroku app, the domain still shows the other website (to which it was initially forwarded), not the Heroku app.

Here are my Google Domains settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the domain name was still "claimed" by the other Heroku app, so I had to log in to the one which had been forwarded on the Heroku console and delete the domain name.  After I did this it could be added with `heroku domains:add www.lizbayardelle.com` and `heroku domains:add lizbayardelle.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to point to `liz-bayardelle.herokuapp.com`, use that.

You've used `www.liz-bayardelle.herokuapp.com`. Visiting that URL displays Heroku's "no such app" page.

Comment: Correct.  The actual heroku link is https://liz-bayardelle.herokuapp.com/, yet the google instructions say "Under Custom resource records, create a CNAME record for www and enter www.(name_of_your_herokusite).herokuapp.com. in the data field then click Add." and if I put in the actual Heroku link it tells me the CNAME shouldn't be a website...